# Phabricator - Drydock/Almanac

Tags: phabricator

I have problem with settings of Drydock/Almanac.

My settings:

### **Drydock**

**Blueprint:**
Name: "Blueprint"
Visible to: "All"
Tags: "Project"
Almanac Services: "service"
Credentials: "K2 DevServer" (ssh key and username is tested and is working)

**Resources**
Are empty.

**Leases**
Are empty.

**Repository Operations**
Are empty.

### **Almanac**

**Network**
Name: "Public network"
Visible to: "All"

**Services**
Name: "service"
Type: "Drydock pool"
Visible to: "All"
Tags: "Project"

**Devices**
Name: "build"
Visible to: "All"
Tags: "Project"

**Interface:**
Address: "192.168.2.171" (address of same machine where Phabricator is running)
Port: 22
Properties: empty
SSH Public keys: empty
BoundServices: "service"

When I click to edit repository -> Automation, select "Blueprint" and run "Test configuration" It returns error:

```
Lease activation failed: [PhabricatorWorkerPermanentFailureException] No active Drydock blueprint exists which can ever allocate a resource for lease "PHID-DRYL-x6dq5ln5ok24nglf4nga".
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you need this in combination with `Harbormaster`:

You should create two Blueprints:

1) `Almanac Host` `Blueprint` (What you did)

In terminal using `./bin/drydock lease --type host` create a Resource from the host.

2) `Working Copy` `Blueprint` (Add the `Almanac Host` in `Use Blueprints`)

Give Authorization whenever needed.

In `Harbormaster` > `Build Plan` add the created `working copy` as the `Blueprint`. You will be able to run the build command manually or automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Although out of the protype stage now Drydock and Almanac have some very rough edges. I can't walk you through specifically how to solve this issue as it varies from case to case but I can tell you where to look.

If you go to the Drydock application then click on blueprints and then click on the blueprint that you are using for the working copy you should see some error listed under the logs section. It will likely be an issue with ssh access or not able to clone a repo due to permissions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am running in the same problem! Unfortunately there is no log in the blueprint which I am using for the working copy under the logs section.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. I overlooked those (not so easy to read) pages of the documentation:
https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/drydock_working_copies
https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/drydock_blueprints/

As [Pouyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371488/pouyan) says, you need to create a working copy. You can do it entirely with the UI:

- go to [phabricator_url]/drydock/blueprint/
- `Create Blueprint` ("+" in the up-right corner)
- Select `Working Copy` and press `Continue`
- `Name`: Working copy of ...
- `Use Blueprints`: select the Almanac blueprint

Then you need to authorize your new blueprint:

- go to [phabricator_url]/drydock/blueprint/
- select the *first* blueprint (not the working copy)
- under `Active authorizations`, click on the one(s) that needs activation
- click on `Approve Authorization`

In Automation, add the working copy blueprint. You will need to authorize it as well (same as above, but selecting the *second* blueprint).

Now you can `Test Configuration` again. To see if everything runs smoothly, you can look at your working copy blueprint page, under `Logs`.